# How to bind a key to button1.text?

Tags: vb.net

I'm quite new to programming, so I'm facing a lot of problems such as this one:

After clicking `button1`, the program should assign the next pushed key(ctrl, for example) to `button1.text`.

**For example:** `Click button1 -> push key X -> button1.text = X`

What I have so far:

```
Private Sub btnTaste1_keydown(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles btnTaste1.KeyDown

    btnTaste1.Text = e.KeyCode.ToString

End Sub
```

But that assigns a pushed key at any time, not only after clicking the button.

Comment: You could use a variable, such as `Dim awaitingText As Boolean` and set it to `True` when you click your button, and then set it to `False` after you press a key.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do this would be to dynamically add and remove the KeyDown handler.

Change your KeyDown to look like this (remove the `Handles` clause):

```
Private Sub btnTaste1_keydown(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs)
```

That will stop that code from automatically being run on every key press.
Now in your button click code, add this:

```
addhandler btnTaste1.Keydown, addressof(btnTaste1_keydown)
```

After you "handle" the key press you should detach the handler so it doesn't get called again (until the button click attaches it again), like this:

```
btnTaste1.Text = e.KeyCode.ToString
removeHandler btnTaste1.Keydown, addressof(btnTaste1_keydown)
```

Eventually you may want to investigate using the Form's `KeyPreview` property and attach the event to the form instead so that you don't need to worry about the complexities of input focus.

Comment: just nothing happens.
but i understand the idea.
 Is it possible to start a keydown-event after klicking the button and stop it again, after i've pushed my desired key?